Fluent-bit tomcat localhost access log is parsing as a single line msg
below is tomcat access log incoming msg
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024:00:51:49 +0000] "GET /TA HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0

Below is fluent-bit.conf file:
  [INPUT]
        Name tail                                               
        Path ${log_paths}/localhost_access_log.*.txt              
        Path_key log.file.path       
        Key message
    
    [FILTER]         
        Name parser            
        Match tomcat-localhost-access*         
        Key_Name message          
        Parser multiline-2    

   [OUTPUT]          
    Name        stdout       
    Match       *

Below is parsers.conf file
#tomcat-localhost_access-logs
#127.0.0.1 - - [27/Aug/2024:00:01:48 +0000] "GET /TA HTTP/1.1" 302 - 0
[PARSER]
    Name multiline-2
    Format regex
    Regex /^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<log_time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<requestmethod>\S+)(?: +(?<urlpath>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<statuscode>[^ ]*) (?<bytessent>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?/

Pls let me know the issue? If i remove Filter incoming msg is displaying in output properly without separated fields. If added Parser, it is failing.

We don't allow reposts of closed questions. Edit the old one to improve it instead.
